# Zip key and value arrays into one object with Dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I need to generate a single object starting from two arrays, one with the key names and the other with the values. I was able to get it using the following code:

```
var keys = ["fieldA","fieldB","fieldC"]
var values = [45,"data", {some: "object"}]
---
(keys zip values) map ((keyValueArray, index) -> 
    {
        (keyValueArray[0]):keyValueArray[1]
    }
) reduce ((singleKeyObject, acc) -> acc ++ singleKeyObject)
```

That code produces this output:

```
{
  "fieldA": 45,
  "fieldB": "data",
  "fieldC": {
    "some": "object"
  }
}
```

Is there any function that replace all these three steps in just one or at least less than the solution I found?

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can eliminate the `map` altogether and do just the `reduce`.

Comment: That would not be performant (using reduce over map)  if the content in the arrays is huge..

Comment: @SalimKhan you say that using `map+reduce` is worst than just `reduce` in this case?

Comment: it would be at par or better. reduce (being not lazy) would have to read the whole array before processing it while map (streams it)  would not need that.

Comment: @SalimKhan `map` may be lazy but if you need to visit every single piece of data (as in this case) `map` + `reduce` > just `reduce` perform the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need use zip or reduce or even concat `++`.

Try this:

```
    %dw 2.0
    output application/json
    var keys = ["fieldA","fieldB","fieldC"]
    var value = [45,"data", {some: "object"}]
    ---
    {
        (  keys map (data,index) -> {((data):value[index])}  )
    }
```

The trick is that you enclosed the expression with curly bracket and parenthesis before the expression

Example:

```
{ 
     ( <expression> )
}
```

Comment: Dynamic elements

Comment: Dynamic elements also entail iterating data, eliminating arrays, collapsing (aka concatenating) objects etc.  This code looks cleaner but I wouldn't claim its more performant than using `zip` and `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

This would do just fine as well..

```
 %dw 2.0
    output application/json
    var keys = ["fieldA","fieldB","fieldC"]
    var value = [45,"data", {some: "object"}]
    ---
   {
          (keys map (data,index) -> (data):value[index])
    }
```